# How to add a timing event

Tags: windows, vb.net, events, timing, toolstripbutton

Is there a way when I click on a ToolStripButton, it shows the WaitCursor and updates the StatusStrip for about 10 seconds, then returns back to normal. I just don't know how to type in the coding.

If someone could guide me through the process. (or even give me the code)

Thank You

J Mahone

Comment: what are you doing that takes **10 seconds**.  what code have you tried?

Comment: The coding I have tries is Me.UseWaitCursor = True ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Saving, please wait" I just don't know how to get the 10 seconds bit

Comment: Why not Set the cursor (`Me.Cursor = WaitCursor`), do your thing, then set it back.  No need to set on a timer.  Unless you are saving the Old Testament, it generally happens fast enough that you dont need a message, especially if the user just clicked Save.

Comment: You have a good point. But I want the application to wait for 10 seconds, you see it is not even saving anything, i just want it to do that. Is it still possible to do?

Comment: by "wait" you mean lock out the user?

Comment: You could use a timer or a thread with a thread.sleep(10000) to do this.  I think there might be a way with Lambda and async that puts is all in one method.  What version of VS/Framework are you using?

Comment: Hi Steve and Plutonix, No, I just want the waitcursor to appear for 10 seconds then go back to normal and the toolstripstatuslabel to appear something diffrent, then change back to 'Ready'.

Comment: then use a timer, set the cursor to Me.Cursor = WaitCursor AND Me.WaitCursor = True.  when the timer goes off, restore them both

Comment: Hi There, Could I ask how to do that? I hardly know anything about timers on vb.net, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a timer:

1:Add a timer from your component toolbox to your form.

2:Set the inteval to 10,000 (this is in milliseconds, 1000 = 1 second)

3:In the timers' "Tick" event, write this code:

```
Timer1.stop 'This assumes your timer it named Timer1
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

4: When you want to make it show the cursor, either have a method to do both these lines and call the method or just write these 2 lines all over the place:

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
Timer1.Start
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use async/await to keep the "normal" program flow.

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
Await Task.Delay(10000)
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```